# In Sharepoint, what is the actual name of the page layout used for the "Article page with with body only" layout option?

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0, page-layout

I need to swap out the out-of-the-box rich text editor with the Telerik editor for all article page layouts. Unfortunately, I only see three article layouts in Sharepoint Designer. When creating a new article page from within Sharepoint, however, it shows 4 article layouts. The one I see missing in Designer is the one with no option for article images.

Does anyone know where I can find the layout labeled as "Article page with body only"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file you are talking about is PageFromDocLayout.aspx.

Comment: @ryan- If i am using sharepoint designer, at which location will i find this page layout?

Comment: @Nitesh This was Corey Roth's answer, not mine. I had only made a minor edit to the original answer.